# jQuery Scrolling Length

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am working with a script to scroll an element on click. It's working properly, however it either scrolls all the way up, or all the way down. I'm new to jquery, and I'm wondering how to make it scroll a little at at time. For example, clicking to scroll down once will take you down a certain length, clicking again scrolls that length again. Also, sometimes it jitters and bugs out when scrolling back up. Any insight on how to fix this is appreciated as well!

Thanks.

Code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var ele   = $('#scroll');
    var speed = 25, scroll = 5, scrolling;

   $('#scroll-up').click(function() {
        // Scroll the element up
        scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
            ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() - scroll );
        }, speed);
    });

    $('#scroll-down').click(function() {
        // Scroll the element down
        scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
            ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() + scroll );
        }, speed);
    });

    $('#scroll-up, #scroll-down').bind({
        click: function(e) {
            // Prevent the default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            if (scrolling) {
                window.clearInterval(scrolling);
                scrolling = false;
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you take out the setInterval function and leave just this line ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() - scroll ); it should go down just a little bit at a time. Your setInterval might be calling that line several times before it clears since your speed is set below 1 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying you want to scroll little at a time but your code is saying scroll UNTIL mouse leaves. If you want to scroll little at a time why would you write a `mouseleave` which clearly stating if it's been scrolling stop now!

If you want to scroll up/down a bit on click, you should get rid of `setInterval` and `mouseleave`.

```
$(function() {
    var ele   = $('#scroll');
    var speed = 25, scroll = 5;

   $('#scroll-up').click(function() {
        // Scroll the element up
        ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() - scroll );
    });

    $('#scroll-down').click(function() {
        ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() + scroll );
    });

    $('#scroll-up, #scroll-down').bind({
        click: function(e) {
            // Prevent the default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fB435/)